# Angular Material: md-autocomplete - how to hide md-autocomplete-suggestions on Enter event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have `md-autocomplete`:

```
<md-autocomplete 
                         md-min-length="1"
                         ng-enter="presEnter();"
                         md-no-cache="true"                        
                         md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
                         md-search-text="searchText" 
                         md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
                         md-item-text="item.name" 
                         placeholder="Search for a vegetable">
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}} :: {{item.type}}</span>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

with directive: `ng-enter`.

My goal: **When user presses `Enter` I want to hide `md-autocomplete-suggestions` dropdown**

I know from HTML I need somehow to call: `$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;` but have no idea how to use `$mdAutocompleteCtrl` in Controller.

I googled and found:

```
$timeout( function() { $scope.$$childHead.$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true; },100);
```

but there is no `$mdAutocompleteCtrl` (at least in my JS, only in HTML and i don't know its scope)

I play with this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbOPgv?editors=101): type 'a' and after dropdown press Enter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `$mdAutocompleteCtrl` is placed as a property on the autocomplete's scope.

First, you need access to the autocomplete element. One way to do that is to put an ID on the autocomplete:

```
<md-autocomplete id='Auto'
                 md-min-length="1"
                 ng-enter="presEnter();"
                 md-no-cache="true"
                 md-selected-item="selectedItem"
                 md-search-text="searchText"
                 md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
                 md-item-text="item.name"
                 placeholder="Search for a vegetable">
```

Then you can use that element to get the inner scope of the autocomplete. Because the autocomplete element itself is on the scope that you provided, you'll want to get the scope of one of the autocomplete's child elements.

```
$scope.presEnter = function(e){
    var autoChild = document.getElementById('Auto').firstElementChild;
    var el = angular.element(autoChild);
    el.scope().$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;
};
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVPZKN?editors=101

Comment: both answers work for me but i prefer yours (more clear). Thank you

Comment: I am totally lost. I cannot see any differences `in action`. It is just a week I started to get to know the AngularJS. Can someone tell me what are the differences? Not in code! I played with all the codes here but the behaviors are the same. Thanks

Comment: @Milban This answer uses a controller to manage the press enter to close logic. Some of the other answers use a directive that is applied as an attribute to the md-autocomplete element. Both options work so I suppose it's a matter of preference. If you're this new to AngularJS then you should read up on controllers and directives. Also, unless you have a good reason to learn AngularJS you should probably at this point be learning the newest Angular or another framework. AngularJS is old and inferior to the latest libraries.

Comment: `el.scope()` is not available when running AngularJs in production settings

Answer (score 10):

*TLDR: Example code that triggers hide http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJvGzp?editors=101*

**The Problem(s):**

First off, the "Angular Way" suggests that manipulating directives in your Controller should be avoided. The Controller should essentially just retrieve (via Services, etc.) and provide the data required to build a view; it generally should avoid caring about exactly what how those views are implemented (i.e. it should know not what directives will be used). There are various good reasons for this, one might be that it makes life much easier when you want to modify the view, such as swapping out directives.

If directives really need to be manually modified, it's better to do so from another directive. This allows more flexibility, and simplifies refactoring later (same example: if swapping out for different autocomplete directives).

Also, although it seems to be the only way to solve the problem in this case, the `$scope.$$childHead.$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden` code seems fairly hacky - unless there is no other choice, one should avoid accessing properties starting with `$$`, and also avoid modifying sibling directives without doing so via shared scope properties.

Unfortunately, after digging into the source code ( on the [master branch](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/autocomplete/js/autocompleteController.js) ), I could not find any nicer way to trigger the hide function than (as you suggested) to grab it's scope and modify the `hidden` property.

Another problem with accessing it via the Controller is that it's a bit more difficult because it's nested through a few other scopes. You can pass the event, grab the DOM node, and pull up it's scope, but that's a lot of irrelevant stuff in a Controller.

**The Solution:**

So instead, we can add a sibling directive, similar to the `ngEnter` example directive that you've included in the Codepen example. Perhaps something a bit more explicit so that it's a bit more obvious what it's doing:

```
.directive('mdHideAutocompleteOnEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$$childHead.$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true; // $scope  modified to scope
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The HTML would simply include this directive when relevant:

```
<md-autocomplete 
               md-hide-autocomplete-on-enter
               md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
               md-item-text="item.name">
     <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.name}} :: {{item.type}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Here's the example, modified with it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJvGzp?editors=101

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. But all this stuff for a so simple operation? I think the directive should be adjusted.

Comment: There are a lot of words in the post, but the code is rather succinct. The words were to begin to explain the why the Controller is the wrong place (separation of concerns: directives for UI, Controller for business logic).
 
I agree that you're entirely correct in the assessment that the library, Angular Material, should provide better hooks for this. :)

Answer (score 4):

The better way to access the controller methods is to target the element and then use the jqLite object to gain access to the controller:

```
var $acElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('Auto'));
var acCtrl = $acElement.controller('mdAutocomplete');
acCtrl.hidden = true;
```

Whenever you access anything using the `scope()` method on an angular element, your implementation will break if you ever want to disable angular debug info.

Answer (score 4):

I think this solution is better because:

- it uses a directive instead of the controller.
- it is simpler than the other given directive solution.

Javascript

```
app.directive('closeOnEnter', function($compile) {
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'mdAutocomplete',
         link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('keydown keypress', function($event) {
               // 13: Enter
               if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
                  var eAcInput = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                  eAcInput.blur();
               }
            });
         },
      };
});
```

HTML

```
<md-autocomplete close-on-enter ... ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing focus on the md-autocomplete input element on enter, you can close md-autocomplete suggestions without using hacky ways that involve messing with the internal `$mdAutocompleteCtrl` controller. This depends on md-autocomplete to automatically hide suggestions when the input element is no longer focused.

1. Wrap your md-autocomplete element in a form (or use a directive like `ng-enter`) and add an ID to the input element using md-input-id

```
  <form ng-submit="vm.handleFormSubmit()">
    <md-autocomplete md-input-id="autocomplete" ...>
    </md-autocomplete>
  </form>
```

2. Call `blur()` on the `#autocomplete` input element

```
handleFormSubmit() {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#autocomplete')).blur();
}
```